# I am trying to render google chart using PHP and MySql but no chart is rendered and no error message is displayed. Is the html code correct?

Tags: php, mysql, error-handling, google-visualization

```
<?php

$host = "localhost";
$username = "root";
$password = "root";
$db = "ujval";

$conn = new mysqli($host, $username, $password, $db);

if($conn->connect_error) {
die ("Connection failed:". $conn->connect_error);
} else {
echo "Awesome";
}
```

Till this point every thing was working fine

```
$sql = "SELECT * FROM sub_list";
$qresult = $conn->query($sql);
$results = array();
while($res = $qresult->fetch_assoc()) {
$results[] = $res;
}

$bar_chart_data = array();

foreach($results as $result) 
{
$bar_chart_data[] = array($result['sub_id'], $result['sub_name']);
}

$bar_chart_data = json_encode($bar_chart_data);
$mysqli_free_result($qresult);
$mysqli_close($conn);
?>
```

I think the major problem is with the section just above. The error what I am getting says:

Slim Application Error
The application could not run because of the following error:

Details

Type: ErrorException
Code: 8
Message: Undefined variable: mysqli_free_result
File: /Applications/MAMP/htdocs/Dream/Dream/templates/charts.php
Line: 31

```
<html>

  <head>
<!--Load the AJAX API-->
    <script type="text/javascript" src="https://www.google.com/jsapi"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">

<!--Load the Visualization API and the piechart package.-->
    google.load("visualization", "1.0", {packages:["bar"]});

<!--Set a callback to run when the Google Visualization API is loaded.-->
    google.setOnLoadCallback(drawChart);


<!--Callback that creates and populates a data table,-->
<!--instantiates the pie chart, passes in the data and-->
<!--draws it.-->
    function drawChart() {
<!--Create the data table.-->
    var data = google.visualization.DataTable();
    data.addColumn('string', 'Age Group');
    data.addColumn('number', 'Number');
    data.addRows($bar_chart_data);

<!--Set chart options-->
    var options = {
      title: ' ' 
    };

<!--Instantiate and draw our chart, passing in some options.-->
    var chart = new google.charts.Bar(document.getElementById('columnchart_material'));

    chart.draw(data, options);

    }

   </script>

</head>
<body>

[enter image description here][1]<!--Div that will hold the pie chart-->

    <div id="columnchart_material" style="width: 900px; height: 500px;"></div>][1]

</body>

</html>
```

This is the resulting HTML code from the browser.

```
Awesome
<html>
  <head>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="https://www.google.com/jsapi"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
    google.load("visualization", "1.0", {packages:["corechart"]});
    google.setOnLoadCallback(drawChart);

    function drawChart() {
      var data = new google.visualization.DataTable();
      data.addColumn('number', 'sub_id');
      data.addColumn('string', 'sub_name');
      data.addRows({$bar_chart_data});
      var options = {
        title: ' '
      };
      var chart = new google.charts.Bar(document.getElementById('columnchart_material')); 
      chart.draw(data, options);
    }

  </script>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div id="columnchart_material" style="width: 900px; height: 500px;"></div>
  </body>
</html>
```

And the error in the browser is showing: 
"Uncaught ReferenceError: bar_chart_data is not defined"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change the last two lines to

```
mysqli_free_result($qresult);
mysqli_close($conn);
```

Then you should not receive that error message any longer.

**EDIT:**

And, this line is not parsed correctly:

```
data.addRows($bar_chart_data);
```

It is not possible to refer to a PHP variable within JavaScript. But it should work better like this:

```
data.addRows(<? echo $bar_chart_data ?>);
```

Then your JSON code should be inserted correctly.

Comment: Thank you. The error has been resolved and I am getting "Awesome" as the message. But the google chart is still not rendered.

Comment: That's a different question.

Comment: If you have trouble with the rendering of the chart, you should either post a new question (and mark this as answered), or edit your original question and specify the problem. An error message would be helpful, or at least the rendered HTML code instead.

Comment: Thank you. I edited the question and accepted your answer.

Comment: It would help if you could insert the *resulting* HTML code that appears in the browser, not only your PHP script. Isn't there an error message given in the JavaScript console?

Comment: I have added the resulting HTML code from the browser.

Comment: For the future, please try to ask not too general questions in one post, like "what is not working here". There might be still more things to fix here. You could help by isolating the problem yourself, as best as you can, and ask one question per post. This will make the whole process more efficient.